# what different is .selector1 .selector2 and .selector1 > .selector2?

Tags: css

what different is `.selector1 .selector2` and `.selector1 > .selector2`? Dont then both indicate the .selector2 is child of .selector1

What is different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`>` means the second element must be an immediate child. Using simply the space, the second element can be found anywhere "underneath" the first element. For example:

```
<ul id="root">
    <li id="a">
        <ul>
            <li id="x"></li>
            <li id="y"></li>
        </ul>
    <li id="b">
        Something
    </li>
</ul>
```

The selector `'#root > li'` only matches `a` and `b`, but `'#root li'` matches `x` and `y` as well.

Answer (score 3):

The first form matches any descendent no matter how many levels down it is, while the second form matches only immediate children.

Take this hierarchy of elements:

```
<div id="Bob" class="selector1">
    <div id="Mary" class="selector2">
        <div id="Alice" class="selector2">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The selector `.selector1 .selector2` will match both Mary and Alice. On the other hand, `.selector1 > .selector2` will only match Mary, because Alice is not an immediate child of a `selector1` element.